# x:Type missing in UWP - How override base control style?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

in WPF I override the basic control styles with the following Code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource  {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource margin}" />
</Style>
```

In UWP the `x:Type` in XAMl is gone. So how can I accomplish the above code in UWP? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can gather from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt210950.aspx), `x:Type` is no longer supported in Universal Windows Apps.

To get around style inheritance, you will need to create a base style which has an `x:Key`, this can be referenced using the `StaticResource` markup for the `BasedOn` property.

```
<Style x:Key="BasicButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    ... (This may contain nothing)
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Button" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource BasicButtonStyle}">
    ...
</Style>
```

Comment: Thx ,but how can I custom my Button baseon Button?

Answer (score 4):

This should be it:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource margin}" />
</Style>
```