# Style inheritance - how to refine a custom default style?

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, uwp

In a WinRT / UWP app (the problem occurs on both platforms), I can define a style that applies to all instances of a certain control, by omitting the `x:Key` attribute, e.g.:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="400"/>
</Style>
```

Now, I'd like to apply certain properties to some buttons *in addition to this default style*:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="TallButtonStyle" BasedOn="...">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
</Style>
```

The problem is: What to fill in as `BasedOn` attribute, so that this style inherits the default style defined above?

In WPF, I could do the following:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="..." BasedOn="{StaticResource  {x:Type Button}}">
```

However, `x:Type` is not available on WinRT / UWP. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562864/xtype-missing-in-uwp-how-override-base-control-style) suggests, I need to assign an `x:Key` to the default style in order to be able to inherit from it:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="WideButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="400"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="TallButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource Button}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
</Style>
```

However, in this case the `WideButtonStyle` is not used as default any more, and I'd need to apply `Style="{StaticResource WideButtonStyle}"` to all my buttons manually, which seams unneessary overhead to me.

Is there any way, to either

1. set a style's `BasedOn` attribute to point to the respective control's default style, or
2. set a style that contains a `x:Key` attribute to be used as standard for all controls of a given type?

BTW, [this related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336314/uwp-xaml-how-to-inherit-from-the-default-styles-using-basedon) does not answer my question, as it shows how to override the *default style defined in the WinRT / UWP platform*, not a custom-made default style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give your default style an `x:Key`, then make an empty style without `x:Key` based on this style. This style will apply to all the instances of a control but will basically be an "reference" to the first style. Than you can create additional styles based on the first style with `x:Key`. Not really an elegant solution but I think you cannot do better.